# A specific push down automaton for a language (PDA)

Tags: algorithm, pushdown-automaton

I'm wondering how could I design a pushdown automaton for this specific language.
I can't solve this..

**L2 = { u ∈ {a, b}∗ : 3 ∗ |u|a = 2 ∗ |u|b + 1 }**

So the number of 'a's multiplied by 3 is equals to number of 'b's multiplied by 2 and added 1.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar corresponding to that language is something like:

```
S -> ab | ba |B
B -> abB1 | baB1 | aB1b | bB1a | B1ab | B1ba
B1 -> aabbbB1 | baabbB1 | [...] | aabbb | baabb | [...]
```

S generates the base case (basically strings with #a = 1 = #b) or B

B generates the base case + B1 (in every permutation)

B1 adds 2 'a' and 3 'b' to the base case (in fact if you keep adding this number of 'a' and 'b' the equation `3#a = 2#b + 1` will always be true!). I didn't finish writing B1, basically you need to add every permutation of 2 'a' and 3 'b'. I think you'll be able to do it on your own :)

When you're finished with the grammar, designing the PDA is simple. More info [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/automata-cfg-to-pda-conversion).

Answer (score 1):

3|u|<sub>a</sub> = 2|u|<sub>b</sub> + 1 <=> 3|u|<sub>a</sub> - 2|u|<sub>b</sub> = 1

The easiest way to design a PDA for this is to implement this equation directly.

For any string *x*, let f(x) = 3|x|<sub>a</sub> - 2|x|<sub>b</sub>.  Then design a PDA such that, after processing any string *x*:

- The stack depth is always equal to abs( floor( f(x)/3 ) );
- The symbol on the top of the stack (if any), reflects the sign of floor( f(x)/3 ).  **You only need 2 kinds of stack symbols**
- The current state number = f(x) mod 3.  Of course **you only need 3 states**.

From the state number and the symbol on top of the stack, you can detect when f(x) = 1, and at that condition the PDA accepts *x* as a string in the language.